# How do create a table with an unique constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create 3 tables, but the table `Award` cannot be created. Within the brackets (`Child`, `Present`) I get an error. What should I do? Table `Present` and table `Child` are created but not table `Award`. I'm not able to create table `Award`, why?

```
create table Child
(
    ID integer primary key,
    name varchar(20) unique not null,
    age integer,
    kind bit
);

create table Presents
(
    ID integer primary key,
    name varchar(20) unique,
    weight float
);

create table Award
(
   ID integer primary key,
   childID integer references Barn(ID),
   presentID integer references Presenter(ID),
   unique(Child, Present),
   antal int
);
```

Comment: You need to call them `childID` and `presentID`, since those are the actual column names in the table.

Comment: Also this isn't the correct way to add a unique constraint to the table.   Please read the CREATE TABLE documentation in MSDN.

Comment: Because Child and Present are NOT columns in your table. I would recommend NOT using ID as a column name. It really should be ChildID and PresentsID in every table. I would also not store age ever. You should store birthdate and calculate it. Also, weight should probably be a numeric instead of float. I can't even begin to fathom what a bit column named "kind" is for.

Comment: really @SeanLange?   Isn't it enough to store whether a child is kind or not?   Do you need some kind of kindness rating?

Comment: @TabAlleman LOL. I have a feeling that column indicates Male/Female but who knows. :)

Comment: Actually, a serious guess would be `kind` indicates the child is/is not in Kindegarten.

Answer (score 3):

Child and Present are not columns in Award.  I believe you want `unique(childID, presentID)`